# Python Guessing Game: Failing any of 5 quizzes skips all left quizzes and go straight to the results

Tags: python

So I am working on a simple python guessing game. There are a total of 5 quizzes. But if I fail any one of them the rest of the quizzes are skipped and goes straight to the results. Please note that some portions of the code are for decoration purposes only.

```py
movie_name = "WRECK IT RALPH"
movie_name2 = "AVENGERS ENDGAME"
movie_name3 = "AVENGERS AGE OF ULTRON"
movie_name4 = "CARS 3"
movie_name5 = "SPIDER-MAN: INTO THE SPIDER-VERSE"
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
print('Guess The Movie!')
print('By Ahmed Shahir Samin')

print('''
Rules and Info:
''')
print('''1. This game is NOT case sensitive. That means you can enter the answers in either upper or lower case or a
   mixture of both of them.
2. Use the hints provided to guess the answer.
3. At the end results will be shown with a format like so:
   LEVEL NO.:CORRECT ANSWER :IF YOUR ANSWER WAS CORRECT OR NOT.''')

print('''LOADING ASSETS........
ASSETS LOADED SUCCESSFULLY.
STARTING GAME FROM LEVEL 1'

GOOD LUCK''')

print('''LEVEL 1: Fill the unfilled movie name: 
W___K __ _AL__
TYPE: Animated, Adventure
STUDIO: DISNEY''')
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('LEVEL 1: Fill the Movie Name: ')
    guess_count += 1
    if guess.upper() == movie_name:
        print('YOU WON!')
        lvl1win = True
        break
else:
    print('SORRY. YOU FAILED LEVEL 1!')
    lvl1win = False

print('''LEVEL 2: Fill the unfilled movie name: 
A___G__S ____A__
TYPE: Action
STUDIO: MARVEL''')
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('LEVEL 2: Fill the Movie Name: ')
    guess_count += 1
    if guess.upper() == movie_name2:
        print('YOU WON!')
        lvl2win = True
        break
else:
    print('SORRY. YOU FAILED LEVEL 2!')
    lvl2win = False

print('''LEVEL 3: Fill the unfilled movie name: 
A___G__S _G_ __ _L_R__
TYPE: Action
STUDIO: MARVEL''')
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('LEVEL 3: Fill the Movie Name: ')
    guess_count += 1
    if guess.upper() == movie_name3:
        print('YOU WON!')
        lvl3win = True
        break
else:
    print('SORRY. YOU FAILED LEVEL 3!')
    lvl3win = False

print('''LEVEL 4: Fill the unfilled movie name: 
___S 3
TYPE: Animated, Racing, Adventure
STUDIO: DISNEY''')
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('LEVEL 4: Fill the Movie Name: ')
    guess_count += 1
    if guess.upper() == movie_name4:
        print('YOU WON!')
        lvl4win = True
        break
else:
    print('SORRY. YOU FAILED LEVEL 4!')
    lvl4win = False

print('''LEVEL 5: Fill the unfilled movie name: 
S____R-M__: I__O T_E ____ER-V___E
TYPE: Action, Animated
STUDIO: MARVEL''')
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('LEVEL 5: Fill the Movie Name: ')
    guess_count += 1
    if guess.upper() == movie_name5:
        print('YOU WON!')
        lvl5win = True
        break
else:
    print('SORRY. YOU FAILED LEVEL 5!')
    lvl5win = False

print('''
Results:
''')

if lvl1win == True:
    print(f'LEVEL 1: {movie_name}: CORRECT!')
if lvl1win == False:
    print(f'LEVEL 1: {movie_name}: WRONG!')
if lvl2win == True:
    print(f'LEVEL 2: {movie_name2}: CORRECT!')
if lvl2win == False:
    print(f'LEVEL 2: {movie_name2}: WRONG!')
if lvl3win == True:
    print(f'LEVEL 3: {movie_name3}: CORRECT!')
if lvl3win == False:
    print(f'LEVEL 3: {movie_name3}: WRONG!')
if lvl4win == True:
    print(f'LEVEL 1: {movie_name4}: CORRECT!')
if lvl4win == False:
    print(f'LEVEL 1: {movie_name4}: WRONG!')
if lvl5win == True:
    print(f'LEVEL 1: {movie_name5}: CORRECT!')
if lvl5win == False:
    print(f'LEVEL 1: {movie_name5}: WRONG!')
print('----------------------END----------------------')


print('''

Credits:
''')

print('''A GAME BY Ahmed Shahir Samin
Hope you guys enjoyed the game. This game was about 102 lines of raw code.
Eid Mubarak and Goodbye.''')
```

The expected result should be if any of the quizzes are failed then it will show the failed message and move on to the next one.

Comment: You never reset the `guess_limit`.

Comment: `guess_count` needs to be reset after each question, not `guess_limit`. Assuming he gives 5 guesses per question.

Comment: Oops. Yes, count, not limit.

Comment: @PMende and @TomNash Neither resetting the ```guess_limit``` or ```guess_count```works.  My bad. I just changed the variable. But not the value. Now it works. Thanks for the help.